# Help need for the reporting

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

[image]

My requirement is to create  a dashboard bar graph X-axis as createddate(MONTHLY) and the y-AXIS (RECORD COUNT)

In the first image i had Groupby N EP/DPI: and write formula as ROWCOUNT/ROWCOUNT

[image]

IN the second Image i had kept the GROUP BY CREATEDDATE/MONTH ?

How can can i write the formula so that i can get the formula as get count 2

not as 3 .how many N EPDPI as there that i need the that count

DASHBOARD: DEC-2013(2 records)
             x          y       axis

This is my criteria Hope.it is so confusing Reply me if you don't understand

Comment: Cant you just use matrix?

Comment: IT is just that simple i would have not post it here .i  had already tried it

Comment: Is the 'N EP/DPI' a textfield on QuoteLineItem, or is it a referral (lookup/master-detail) to another object?

Comment: It is a text field from quote line item

Comment: ok. Just checking. If it would have been a referral, you could use this solution: http://www.ebsta.com/salesforce-power-of-one/

Comment: for plain textfield, I'm afraid there is no standard solution. Or you'd have to change the grouping to Quote instead of N EP/DPI. But that will likely not meet your requirement..